# So I made a custom status so my discord.js bot shows the number of members in the server in its status

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's the code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.memberCount} Members!`);
});
```

Instead of showing the number of members, it shows "undefined"
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  const memberCount = client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)
  client.user.setActivity(`${memberCount} Members!`);
});
```

Since Discord.js **v13** you also have to make sure to enable the needed **intents** in your `index.js` when creating your client. An example:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

If you want to enable more than one, just split them with a comma, e.g:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
      Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
  });
```

*Since you want to count all **members** from all **guilds** you can use this example for your code*

Here's a [list of all intents available](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Comment: I tried it out but, now, instead of undefined, it shows 0 members...

Comment: Have you enabled the needed intents?

Comment: You mean the privilileged intents? Yeah I have.

Comment: So you have enabled the intents in the discord developer portal **and** when creating your client in your startup file?

Comment: Wait, wdym when creating my client in my startup file, should I add somethin in the index.js file after I enable the intents from the dev portal?

Comment: Can we talk on discord, I found your username in your profile...

Comment: I updated the answer, take a look at it ^^

Comment: Ummm, actually I only want to display all the members from a particular server and not all members from all the servers the bot is in

Comment: Even in this case you need the intents when you want to access values that are inside a guild. And please update your question because you didn't say, that you only want to count specific guilds

Comment: Just replace your client with my second example

Comment: 1 more thing uhh, the code you sent is for discord.js v13, I use v12 because I'm more comfy with it so...

Comment: Why didn't you say that before ._. Please write this in your question

Comment: We can't help you if your question only contains 5% of information

Comment: I'm sooo sorry, so what do I do now? I used the `const memberCount1 = client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)` code you sent and it shows 0 instead of the actual number of members.
Maybe we can take this convo to discord, I've sent a friend req to you